# Parenthesis in TSQL - strange, expected, or bug?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Try running these four SQL commands (I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2012, connecting to SQLServer 2012 11.0):

```
select 'hello' from anytable

(select 'hello' from anytable)

select 'hello' from anytable order by 1

(select 'hello' from anytable order by 1)
```

The first three run just fine.  The fourth one gives the error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'order'.

Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: Looks like a **BUG**

Comment: @NoDisplayName -- Agreed.

Comment: Haven't figured out exactly why, but `(select 'hello' from anytable) order by 1` works.

Answer (score 2):

By using parentheses, you indicating that the query is a sub-query, and you can't use order by operations in a sub-query.

Comment: then you can use `top` keyword to eliminate that error in `subquery` but here even after using `top` it is showing error

Comment: Yes,was originally using TOP, and it didn't work.  Simplifying it down, it reduced to the above.  Which I think is weird...

Comment: Can you try `top 100 percent`?